# How to get a token from Azure AD OAuth2 implicit flow?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, token

I am new in using command CURL to get token. I want command format to be used in CURL.

I have this information from customer :

```
Authentication:
Azure Active Directory OAuth2-Flow.
Type: oauth2/ Flow: implicit
Authorization URL: 
Service Principal (Client ID & Client Secret)
Required Authorization/Scope: /provider/XXXX/XXX/BillingAccounts/{billingAccountId}
```

I tried this but , I am not getting the token , I got anerror :

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' \
--header 'Content-Type:application/json' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=' \
--data-urlencode 'code='
```

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADSTS9000410: Malformed JSON.\r\nTrace ID: daeb9aad9e73\r\nTimestamp: 2022-06-01 11:17:57Z","error_codes":[9000410],"timestamp":"2022-06-01 1
```

Can anyone help as soon as possible?

Answer (score 0):

I  reproduced the issue by keeping content_type as `application/json`.
I got the same error `AADSTS9000410: Malformed JSON`.

[image]

- According to [RFC 6749 - Section 4.1.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.3) definition ,the client
  should make  request to the token endpoint by sending the  parameters
  client_id ,grant_type,code, redirect uri, etc.. using the
  ***application/x-www-form-urlencoded*** `format` per Appendix B with a character encoding of UTF-8 .

***I tried changing the content type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded and recieved the token successfully.***

**CURL Request:**

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/06xxxxxxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=cxxxxxxxxxxxx698' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=xxxxxxxxA' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=' \
--data-urlencode 'code=' \
--data-urlencode 'redirect_url='
```

**Result:**

[image]

***So please change the content type to get token successfully.***